# Checking if no item is selected in checkbox MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a button command which can only be executed in this case:

```
  public bool CanClick
        {
            get
            {
                return (DateX.HasValue) &&
                       (DateY.HasValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Str.NomStr)

            }

        }
```

The ComboBox `SelectedItem` is bound to:

```
 private Structure _str;
    public Structure Str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("Str");
        }
    }
```

Once I start filling fields (the dates etc.), I get the error saying that

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   Str.get returned null

The question is why I'm getting this if I'm actually checking If it's null or not?

Comment: you could use the `?` operator to check for null => `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Str?.NomStr)` it is called the [null-conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't initialization your `_str` object, `_str` will point to `NULL`

when you `get` Str you can check `if==null`, then set a default value.

```
private Structure _str;
public Structure Str
{
    get {
        if(_str == null)
           _str = new Structure();
        return _str; 
    }
    set
    {
        _str = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("Str");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

if `Str==null` didn't set value, it means can't click.

You can try to use this code

Because the `&&` need to let right side and left side condition be `true`.

the right side is `false` it will return `false`. will not execute left side condition.

```
public bool CanClick
{
    get
    {
        return (DateX.HasValue) &&
               (DateY.HasValue) && (Str!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Str.NomStr))
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two values that I have to pass in the constructor, what I'm supposed to pass? since values are supposed to be retrieved form the database in the first place.

Comment: if `Str==null` didn't set value, it mean can't click right?

Comment: yeah, that's it.

Comment: Str != null (alone) will work while adding the IsNullOrEmpty  is going to return the same error. Thank you!